# Mach Kernel vs. XNU

Tags: kernel

When I ran `$ls` on my root directory a file `/mach_kernel` was found.  I'm assuming this is the OSX kernel.  I always thought that OSX used the XNU hybrid kernel, so why is this file called "MACH"? I'm running Lion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what the [Wikipedia page on XNU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNU) says, XNU is based on Mach. Since OS X started using the Mach kernel and now uses a derivative of it, they probably just kept the kernel's file name the same so they didn't have to tweak firmware during upgrades or with new machine releases.

Answer (score 2):

The file is called /mach_kernel for historic reasons; XNU is, indeed a hybrid of Mach and a BSD layer (forget Wikipeida, there's [http://www.amazon.com/Mac-OS-iOS-Internals-Apples/dp/1118057651](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118057651) which seems more definitive).

In actuality, this kernel isn't the exact image which gets loaded - there is a pre linked kernel cache (with all the necessary kexts) in /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.kext.caches/Startup.

Comment: preloaded not prelinked